# RoR understanding deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku

I am VERY new to RoR(going through Michael Hartl's tutorial now). I understand there are three states(?) that your app can be in: development, production, and test. And each state typically uses different database types.

I've created a blank rails app, put it under git, and deployed it to heroku. That all works. Is my app in the production state on heroku or is it still in development? How do you check?

I think i remember reading the Gemfile specifies the resources to install in the different states. Does heroku default to use whatever is specified in the production block?  or am i way off?

my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.11'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3'
```

Comment: Heroku apps all default to production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check by looking at the output of `heroku config` you're looking for the RAILS_ENV and/or RACK_ENV, it will be set to production by default.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku will use produciton by default. That's why you should specify production gems separate of your other gems.

For example specifically on Heroku you'll want to add the 'pg' gem because they're using Postgre database.

```
gem 'pg', :group => :production
```

But since you only need this in production, there's no need to have it in development. Same as there is no need for the sqlite gem to be in your production environment.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec' # or any other testing gems, etc.
end
```

Comment: hmm interesting. I don't have the 'pg' gem in my Gemfile but the database is working on heroku. Why is that? Does it just disregard the sqlite3 gem and automatically us 'pg' even though it's not referenced?

Comment: Yes it will add the gem automatically, but it's a good practice to specify your production gems, since there might be some which heroku won't include automatically.